# MetroFramework MenuStrip Toolbox issue

Tags: c#, package, microsoft-metro, frame, menustrip

I will talk short and specific:

http://prnt.sc/d2t8k7

I installed packages for MetroFramework but there's no `MetroMenuStrip` and the other tools.

When I search the web I see too much examples about `MetroMenuStrip`. But nobody has any problem like mine.

I tried with all these package codes :

- Install-Package Winform.Metroframework
- Install-Package MetroFramework
- Install-Package MetroModernUI
- Install-Package MetroFramework.Design

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reference the types programmatically? Perhaps your toolbox view is [stale](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1212397/622391).

Comment: May you describe your question verbose and extensive instead? An edit to your question would be welcome :-)

Comment: I need to add more tool in Metro Tab . There's too much tool but I have only 20 .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way ...

I added the MenuStrip to this framework by writing this codes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ModernUISample.metro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Menustrip for ModernUI-GUIs
    /// </summary>
    public class MetroMenuStrip : System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MetroMenuStrip()
            : base()
        {
            Renderer = new metroToolStripRenderer();
            Font = MetroUI.Style.BaseFont;
            ForeColor = MetroUI.Style.ForeColor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnItemAdded-Event we adjust the font and forecolor of this item
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnItemAdded(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnItemAdded(e);

            e.Item.Font = MetroUI.Style.BaseFont;
            e.Item.ForeColor = MetroUI.Style.ForeColor;
        }
    }
}
```

create a file in your project.
and create class in this file as "MetroMenuStrip.cs"

and use this code.